# Javascript detect if jquery plugin is working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin called iframetracker.
The plugin works fine on pc at least newest browsers and same for newest phones.
However i want to find if the plugin is not working for older phones.
Is there any way to do it? Thanks

Comment: It's not your job to write unit tests for a 3rd-party script, but the **author's** job.

Comment: If plugin creates some additional content, than just check if it's presented in DOM. If not - plugin is not working.

Comment: @Justinas based on your answer i found it creates an input field with id focus_retriever however it is always returning false.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong
`if(document.getElementById("focus_retriever")){ alert("Exists") } else { alert("Not found"); }`

Comment: @vanmathikk Maybe it's added async and you are checking it before it's added to DOM?

Comment: I tried on older devices, the div still get's loaded on them but the plugin does not work @Justinas and idea what to do now? Thanks